# JAXB Marshal creates part of file before error occurs

Tags: java, file, jaxb, marshalling, opc-ua

I know there are a lot of topics regarding JAXB Marshal already solved, but I don't find any solution which fits for my problem.
I'm trying to marshal an object to a xml file. A part of this file is created, but jaxb stops exactly at the same position every time with the error:

***com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: Neither class [Lorg.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.LocalizedText; nor any of the associated superclasses are known to this context***

The function where the output file is created:

```
public static void storeInformationModel(UANodeSet uaNodeSet, String file) {

        File outputFile = new File(file);

        try {

            JAXBContext outputJaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(
                    "databases.org.opcfoundation.ua._2011._03.uanodeset",
                    databases.org.opcfoundation.ua._2011._03.uanodeset.UANodeSet.class.getClassLoader());

            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = outputJaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(uaNodeSet, outputFile);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(uaNodeSet, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
```

Here is a part of my output file:

```
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=19288</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=6728</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=18176</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=18177</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=18192</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=18194</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=6027</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=6022</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=6117</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=15196</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=6170</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=15200</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition" IsForward="false">ns=5;s=UpdateInterval</Reference>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasSubtype" IsForward="false">ns=0;i=62</Reference>
    </References>
</UAVariableType>
<UAVariable DataType="NodeId{ns=0, id=21}" ValueRank="1" ArrayDimensions="0" AccessLevel="1" UserAccessLevel="1" MinimumSamplingInterval="-1.0" Historizing="false" NodeId="ns=0;i=7591" BrowseName="0:EnumStrings" WriteMask="0" UserWriteMask="0">
    <DisplayName>EnumStrings</DisplayName>
    <References>
        <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition
```

Two things confuse me:

1. The marshal shouldn't use this class:
   ***[Lorg.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.LocalizedText***

It should use a class from a specific package within my project which has the same name.

2. A part of my file is created before JAXB stops and the problem from 1. appears later in the marshal process.

Would be very nice if someone can help me. If you need more snapshots of my files, just ask me. I can post it here.

---

***EDIT:***

This is my LocalizedText class

```
package databases.org.opcfoundation.ua._2011._03.uanodeset;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;


/**
 * <p>Java-Klasse für LocalizedText complex type.
 * 
 * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="LocalizedText">
 *   &lt;simpleContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="&lt;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>string">
 *       &lt;attribute name="Locale" type="{http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd}Locale" default="" />
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/simpleContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "LocalizedText", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class LocalizedText {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Locale")
    protected String locale;

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der value-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der value-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der locale-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getLocale() {
        if (locale == null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return locale;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der locale-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setLocale(String value) {
        this.locale = value;
    }

}
```

The only thing which I do with my LocalizedText class is to use it in a list. Like following example:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({
    UAType.class,
    UAInstance.class
})
public class UANode {

    @XmlElement(name = "DisplayName")
    protected List<LocalizedText> displayName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Description")
    protected List<LocalizedText> description;
    @XmlElement(name = "Category")
    protected List<String> category;
```

The only way I'm accessing the list:

```
public List<LocalizedText> getDisplayName() {
    if (displayName == null) {
        displayName = new ArrayList<LocalizedText>();
    }
    return this.displayName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The marshal shouldn't use this class:
>   [Lorg.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.LocalizedText

This is a Java-internal notation that says that there is an array of LocalizedText trying to be serialized. Arrays usually have certain classes that the JVM uses to internally manage them:

```
jshell> Object foo=new Object[4];
foo ==> Object[4] { null, null, null, null }

jshell> foo.getClass().toString()
$10 ==> "class [Ljava.lang.Object;"  <<<--- this is such a class
```

Arrays can have problems when marshalling. Because of this, many people use collections instead.

Examples on how to serialize lists can be found [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/). Maybe lists will save you from your problem.

Maybe a simple `@XmlRootElement` annotation on LocalizedText would do the trick.

> A part of my file is created before JAXB stops and the problem from 1.
>   appears later in the marshal process.

Marshalling goes through all fields, one after the other. If it encounters a problem within its process, it might well abort then.

Comment: I tried the @XmlRootElement -> got same the error.

Is a List<...> which is null maybe the reason for the error?

Comment: Null references shouldn't be a problem for JAXB.

Comment: I think I found the origin of the problem. I have to marshal a list of objects of unkown type and one possible type is the LocalizedText. So I think while marshalling jaxb dosen't know where to look for the LocalizedText and starts searching somewhere else in my project for that type. But I don't know how to fix that. (I tried @XmlSeeAlso, set the specific package, set all classes manually -> still the same error)